# jQuery Selecting multiple, different-type, elements in td

Tags: jquery-selectors

Given this  table structure:

```
<table id="tblBranchDetails">
    <tr>
        <td width="120px">Branch:</td>
        <td id="branchName" class="branchData">
            <label id="lblBranchName"></label>
            <input type="text" id="txtBranchName" class="hideOnLoad editBranchInfo" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Address Line 1:</td>
        <td id="branchAddress1" class="branchData">
            <label id="lblAddress1"></label>
            <input type="text" id="txtAddress1" class="hideOnLoad editBranchInfo" />
        </td>
    </tr>...
```

I'm trying to select the label and input in each td so I can clear the label's text and hide the input.

This gives me the text in the label (verified in the console):

```
$('table#tblBranchDetails tr td:nth-child(2):eq(0)').text();
```

So I know I can clear the label's text with ".text('')"

Having figured that out, I thought this would give me the value of the input:

```
$('table#tblBranchDetails tr td:nth-child(2):eq(1)').val()
```

But it gives me the value of the label in the next td. So obviously I'm using the :nth-child() and :eq() functions wrong.

What's the correct way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I was nuking this.

Here's the solution:

```
$('#btnShowBranchEditBoxes').click(function() {
    $('#tblBranchDetails tr').find('label').fadeOut(200);
    $('#tblBranchDetails tr').find('.editBranchInfo').delay(200).fadeIn(200);

    // Replace the buttons
    $('table#tblBranchDetails input#btnShowBranchEditBoxes').fadeOut(200);
    $('table#tblBranchDetails input.btnEditBranch').delay(200).fadeIn(200);
});
```